# Can Ektron Do This in SEO?

Tags: content-management-system, seo, ektron

Can tell me if Ektron can do these things in SEO?

- XHTML Compliant - Renders in XHTML compliant mark-up out of the box
- Canonical URLs - Able to specific a canonical URL for a single page SEO
- Friendly URLs - Able to create and configure SEO friendly URLs and formats
- XML Site Map - Able to dynamically and automatically generate an XML Site Map Granular
- Site Map Priorities - Able to set XML sitemap priorities in the page admin
- Semantic Menu - A menu system that uses semantic mark-up
- Google Analytics Integration - Full integration of the Google Analytics script
- Search Engine Submission - Allows you to submit the website to a variety of search engines from an admin interface
- XHTML Compatible Controls - All controls used (menus, grids, etc.) render XHTML compliant mark-up

Comment: I think you can get all the things in their website http://www.ektron.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - XHTML Compliant - Renders in XHTML compliant mark-up out of the box

Not sure. You'll want to download the [Developer starter site](http://www.ektron.com/solutions/startersites/) to check the control you are interested in. If you're concerned about accessibilty, I several controls have a 508 Compliance switch.

> - Canonical URLs - Able to specific a canonical URL for a single page SEO

In theory yes, in practise no.

> - Friendly URLs - Able to create and configure SEO friendly URLs and
>     formats

Yes. Option for manual, regex and automatic aliasing.

> - XML Site Map - Able to dynamically and automatically generate an XML Site
>     Map Granular
> - Site Map Priorities - Able to set XML sitemap priorities in the page
>     admin

Don't think this is out of the box. You would need to look at a custom solution.

> - Semantic Menu - A menu system that uses semantic mark-up

Not out of the box. You would need to customise the mark-up via XSLT.

> - Google Analytics Integration - Full integration of the Google Analytics
>     script

Yes, out of the box. [See here for some help implimenting this](http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=29343).

> - Search Engine Submission - Allows you to submit the website to a variety
>     of search engines from an admin
>     interface

Not that I am aware of.

> - XHTML Compatible Controls - All controls used (menus, grids, etc.)
>     render XHTML compliant mark-up

See my answer to question 1. Out of the box - no, but depends on which controls you are using.

As [Justin Niessner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551813/can-ektron-do-this-in-seo/3551851#3551851) mentions, there is the option to overcome any of this via custom work. To help with your evaluatation, I recommend downloading the Developer starter site and having a look at the default markup of the control.

Also, there is an [Ektron forum](http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=topics&f=88) which is quite vibrant.

Edit - To clarify, I am not employed nor speak for Ektron. Just a developer who is working on the platform.

Comment: Thank you so much for your honest and thorough answer. The answer for any CMS is usually, "yes, but some work... yada, yada." One last question that I missed. Does it support HTTP 301 Redirects for pages that either moved, the URL changed, or no longer exist?

Comment: HTTP 301 Redirects - no. You would need to do this with custom code. See http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=26372

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Ektron's CMS400 can do everything that you have listed there. It's all up to the developer to implement everything though (and it's a hell of a lot of work to get it all working correctly).